# How can I set http Header Data in WicketTester

Tags: http-headers, wicket, wicket-tester

I have web application that is behind a proxy. If the user has logged in, an http-header is set.  I have a page that checks the header, to make sure the user isn't logged in.  How can I add the header to the `MockHttpRequest` generated by WicketTester?

My current unit test looks like the following:

```
  public void testLoggedinViaProxy()
  {
      wt.destroy();
      wt = new WicketTester(new AbstractApplicationHelper());
      wt.setupRequestAndResponse();
      wt.getServletRequest().addHeader("myheader", "someValue");
      wt.createRequestCycle();
      cl=(CSSDLogin)wt.startPage(CSSDLogin.class);
      wt.assertRenderedPage(AppBasePageHelper.class);
  }
```

**UPDATE:**  I'm using 1.4.17 in a production website. I don't intend on upgrading to 1.5.X until it's a full release out of the Release Candidate/Milestone Stages.
the call to `wt.setupRequestAndResponse();` was an attempted fix for [Wicket-1215](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1215)
which I found from [How Do you Set A Custom Session when unit-testing with-Wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456810/how-do-you-set-a-custom-session-when-unit-testing-with-wicket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use Wicket 1.4. In 1.5 there is org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.addRequestHeader(String, String).